# Cannot Autowiring Spring MQTT

Tags: java, spring, mqtt, iot, autowired

**Spring 2.5.3 and Java 1.8**

I want to send a json data to a mqtt topic but i cannot autowiring my Interface and i'm getting null pointer exception when i try with no autowiring.

When i try it this message shows up;

```
Could not autowire. No beans of 'MqttGateway' type found. 
 Inspection info:
Reports autowiring problems on injection points of Spring beans:
```

My Controller;

```
    package com.example.mqtt.Controller;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.JsonObject;
import com.example.mqtt.MqttGateway;
    
    
    
    @RestController
    public class MqttController {
    
        @Autowired
        MqttGateway mqttGateway;
    
        @PostMapping("/sendMessage")
        public ResponseEntity<?> publish(@RequestBody String mqttMessage){
    
            try {
                JsonObject convertObject = new Gson().fromJson(mqttMessage, JsonObject.class);
                mqttGateway.senToMqtt(convertObject.get("message").toString(), convertObject.get("topic").toString());
                return ResponseEntity.ok("Success");
            }catch(Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
                return ResponseEntity.ok("fail");
            }
        }
    
    }
```

My Interface;

```
package com.example.mqtt;

import org.springframework.integration.annotation.MessagingGateway;
import org.springframework.integration.mqtt.support.MqttHeaders;
import org.springframework.messaging.handler.annotation.Header;

@MessagingGateway(defaultRequestChannel = "mqttOutboundChannel")
public interface MqttGateway {

    void senToMqtt(String data, @Header(MqttHeaders.TOPIC) String topic);

}
```